# How to preg_replace links so that the hash is kept

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have huge online php fileset that is made dynamically.
It has links, even some invalid ones with quotes (made with frontpage)

```
index2.php?page=xd
index2.php?page=xj asdfa
index2.php?page=xj%20aas
index2.php?page=xj#jumpword
index2.php?page=gj#jumpword with spaces that arenot%20
index2.php?page=afdsdj#jumpword%20with
index2.php?page=xj#jumpword with "quotes" iknow


$input_lines=preg_replace("/(index2.php?page\=.*)(#[a-zA-Z0-9_ \\"]*)(\"\>)/U", "$0 --> $2", $input_lines);
```

I want all of those to be just with the # -part and not have the index2.php?page=* part.

I could not get this to work in whole evening. So please help.

Comment: `preg_replace("/^index2.php?page\=[^#]*/", "", $input_lines)`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get attributes from the URL (ex: what is after the `#`), like so:

```
$urls = array(
    'index2.php?page=xd',
    'index2.php?page=xj asdfa',
    'index2.php?page=xj%20aas',
    'index2.php?page=xj#jumpword',
    'index2.php?page=gj#jumpword with spaces that arenot%20',
    'index2.php?page=afdsdj#jumpword%20with',
    'index2.php?page=xj#jumpword with "quotes" iknow',
    );

foreach($urls as $url){
    echo 'For "' . $url . '": ';
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    echo isset($parsed['fragment']) ? $parsed['fragment'] : 'DID NOT WORK';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Output:

> For "index2.php?page=xd": DID NOT WORK
>
> For "index2.php?page=xj asdfa": DID NOT WORK
>
> For "index2.php?page=xj%20aas": DID NOT WORK
>
> For "index2.php?page=xj#jumpword": jumpword
>
> For "index2.php?page=gj#jumpword with spaces that arenot%20": jumpword with spaces that arenot%20
>
> For "index2.php?page=afdsdj#jumpword%20with": jumpword%20with
>
> For "index2.php?page=xj#jumpword with "quotes" iknow": jumpword with "quotes" iknow

Comment: No feedback from the op.. I assume it's fixed xD